# rspec - how can I override the rspec format for one repository

Tags: ruby, rspec

I test against 10 different repos.
9 of them don't specify format and so get the standard dots `[......*...F....]` that I like.

However one of them have a .rspec file that specifies `format=documentation' and I get the "long" format, i.e.

```
...
returns a location
returns location with vehicle counts
wont include daily parking prices
...
```

How could I override this without making any changes within that repository?

I've tried putting a `.rspec` file with `--format=progress` in my `~` directory but this doesn't override it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the project already has a `.rspec` file in the root with a different formatter, you can add a `.rspec-local` file and `.gitignore` it.  Within this `.rspec-local` config file, you can add your own custom options like:

```
--format progress
```

This file will override the project `.rspec` file for all settings.

This will allow you to keep a local, un-checked in file for that project without committing anything to the repo.

You may need to also set the global ignore file name with:

*nix:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore'
```

Windows:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile "%USERPROFILE%\.gitignore"
```

You can show which file is currenrtly used for your current .gitignore file with:

```
$ git config --global core.excludesfile
```

If you get no output then you need to add one as detailed above.

Once added, the output from the above command is (e.g.) `~/.gitignore`